# C# analog of multi-variable iteration in Python?

Tags: c#, python, multidimensional-array, iteration

In Python one can iterate over multiple variables simultaneously like this:

```
my_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

for a, b, c in my_list:
    pass
```

Is there a C# analog closer than this?

```
List<List<int>> myList = new List<List<int>> {
    new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 },
    new List<int> { 4, 5, 6 }
};

foreach (List<int> subitem in myList) {
    int a = subitem[0];
    int b = subitem[1];
    int c = subitem[2];
    continue;
}
```

Edit - Just to clarify, the exact code in question was having to assign a name to each index in the C# example.

Comment: Note: This is merely an instance of tuple unpacking (which also allows parallel assignments `a, b = ...`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not too different from what you have but how about this ?

```
foreach (var subitem in myList.Select(si => new {a = si[0], b = si[1], c = si[2]})
{
                int a = subitem.a;
                int b = subitem.b;
                int c = subitem.c;
                continue;
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the `new {...}` bit is doing?

Comment: new {...} creates an anonymous type. You can search on c# anonymous types; there is a lot of info out there. Here's a blog post I was able to find. http://west-wind.com/weblog/posts/189329.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
var myList = new[] {Tuple.Create(1, 2, 3), Tuple.Create(4, 5, 6)};
foreach (var tuple in myList)
{
    //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C# does not have special constructs for this, and not for multiple assignments either

```
a, b = 1, 2
```

is not possible in c#.

You should also note that lists of lists are not really c# style. You typically create a class with `a`, `b` and `c` properties and keep a list of those all the way through.

Comment: I am surprised to hear that "list of lists" is not C# style. Isn't this kind of thing so fundamental that it's not really a matter of language style, and the "style" is more a question of how you do what the OP is asking?

Comment: @tenfour, In code I come across at work and in the .NET framework you rarely see `List<List<T>>` unless you really have matrix kind of data. I can't remember seeing any real good quality c# code with each inner list having the same length and the position in the inner list magically determines the meaning (as in the question). Have a look at `Point`, `Size` etc, they are "just" pairs of data, but have explicit naming of their parameters.

Comment: True - actually I just realized that there is an assumption that the inner list always contains exactly 3 items, which changes everything. I was thinking more something like `List<User>` where `User` has a member `public IEnumerable<Patent> Patents;`. And asking 'how does one get a list of all patents given a `List<User>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your out extension method that using lambda expression can do this.

But at the end it will be something like:

for(int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++){
 int a = tab[0];
 int b = tab[1];
 int c = tab[2];
}

This is only code "sugar", that IMHO should be not used in shared code.